# How to use filter in this situation, can not modify the structure using filter

Tags: filters, oop, codex, wp-error

**plugins/idx-broker-platinum/idx/shortcodes/register-impress-shortcodes.php**

This is the plugin file where I need to use a filter to override the structure.

 Filter name:

> impress_showcase_property_html

> class **Register_Impress_Shortcodes**

```
<?php

/**
 * Property_showcase_shortcode function.
 *
 * @access public
 * @param array $atts (default: array())
 * @return void
 */
public function property_showcase_shortcode( $atts = array() ) {
    extract(
        shortcode_atts(
            array(
                'max'           => 4,
                'use_rows'      => 1,
                'num_per_row'   => 4,
                'show_image'    => 1,
                'order'         => 'default',
                'property_type' => 'featured',
                'saved_link_id' => '',
                'agent_id'      => '',
                'styles'        => 1,
                'new_window'    => 0,
                'colistings'    => 1,
            ),
            $atts
        )
    );

    if ( ! empty( $styles ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'impress-showcase' );
    }

    $output = '';
    if ( ( $property_type ) === 'savedlinks' ) {
        $properties = $this->idx_api->saved_link_properties( $saved_link_id );
        $output    .= '<!-- Saved Link ID: ' . $saved_link_id . ' -->';
    } else {
        $properties = $this->idx_api->client_properties( $property_type );
        $output    .= '<!-- Property Type: ' . $property_type . ' -->';
    }

    // Force type as Array.
    $properties = json_encode( $properties );
    $properties = json_decode( $properties, true );

    // If no properties or an error, load message
    if ( empty( $properties ) || ( isset( $properties[0] ) && $properties[0] === 'No results returned' ) || isset( $properties['errors']['idx_api_error'] ) ) {
        if ( isset( $properties['errors']['idx_api_error'] ) ) {
            return $output .= '<p>' . $properties['errors']['idx_api_error'][0] . '</p>';
        } else {
            return $output .= '<p>No properties found</p>';
        }
    }

    $total = count( $properties );
    $count = 0;

    $column_class = '';

    if ( 1 == $use_rows ) {
        // Max of four columns
        $number_columns = ( $num_per_row > 4 ) ? 4 : (int) $num_per_row;

        // column class
        switch ( $number_columns ) {
            case 0:
                $column_class = 'columns small-12 large-12';
                break;
            case 1:
                $column_class = 'columns small-12 large-12';
                break;
            case 2:
                $column_class = 'columns small-12 medium-6 large-6';
                break;
            case 3:
                $column_class = 'columns small-12 medium-4 large-4';
                break;
            case 4:
                $column_class = 'columns small-12 medium-3 large-3';
                break;
        }
    }

    if ( ! isset( $new_window ) ) {
        $new_window = 0;
    }

    $target = $this->target( $new_window );

    if ( 'low-high' == $order ) {
        // sort low to high
        usort( $properties, array( $this->idx_api, 'price_cmp' ) );
    }

    if ( 'high-low' == $order ) {
        usort( $properties, array( $this->idx_api, 'price_cmp' ) );
        $properties = array_reverse( $properties );
    }

    // Used to hold agent data when matching for colistings.
    $agent_data;

    foreach ( $properties as $prop ) {

        if ( ! empty( $agent_id ) ) {
            // Check if listing agent ID matches agent's IDX ID.
            if ( empty( $prop['userAgentID'] ) || (int) $agent_id !== (int) $prop['userAgentID'] ) {
                // If colistings is enabled, check for match.
                if ( $colistings ) {
                    if ( array_key_exists( 'coListingAgentID', $prop ) ) {
                        // Check if $agent_data is already set, if not grab a new copy to get MLS-provided agent ID.
                        if ( empty( $agent_data ) ) {
                            $agent_data = $this->idx_api->idx_api( 'agents?filterField=agentID&filterValue=' . $agent_id, IDX_API_DEFAULT_VERSION, 'clients', [], 7200, 'GET', true );
                        }
                        // Check the listing's coListingAgentID against the agent's raw MLS-provided ID, continues if no match.
                        if ( empty( $agent_data['agent'][0]['listingAgentID'] ) || $agent_data['agent'][0]['listingAgentID'] !== $prop['coListingAgentID'] ) {
                            continue;
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Listing does not have coListingAgentID field data to match against.
                        continue;
                    }
                } else {
                    // Colistings setting is not enabled.
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

        if ( ! empty( $max ) && $count == $max ) {
            return $output;
        }

        $prop_image_url = $prop['image']['0']['url'] ?? $prop['image']['1']['url'] ?? plugins_url( '/idx-broker-platinum/assets/images/noPhotoFull.png' );

        if ( 1 == $use_rows && $count == 0 && $max != '1' ) {
            $output .= '<div class="shortcode impress-property-showcase impress-row">';
        }

        if ( empty( $prop['propStatus'] ) ) {
            $prop['propStatus'] = 'none';
        }

        $count++;

        // Add Disclaimer when applicable.
        if ( isset( $prop['disclaimer'] ) && ! empty( $prop['disclaimer'] ) ) {
            foreach ( $prop['disclaimer'] as $disclaimer ) {
                if ( in_array( 'widget', $disclaimer ) ) {
                    $disclaimer_text = $disclaimer['text'];
                    $disclaimer_logo = $disclaimer['logoURL'];
                }
            }
        }
        // Add Courtesy when applicable.
        if ( isset( $prop['courtesy'] ) && ! empty( $prop['courtesy'] ) ) {
            foreach ( $prop['courtesy'] as $courtesy ) {
                if ( in_array( 'widget', $courtesy ) ) {
                    $courtesy_text = $courtesy['text'];
                }
            }
        }

        $prop = $this->set_missing_core_fields( $prop );

        // Get URL and add suffix if one exists
        if ( isset( $prop['fullDetailsURL'] ) ) {
            $url = $prop['fullDetailsURL'];
        } else {
            $url = $this->idx_api->details_url() . '/' . $prop['detailsURL'];
        }

        if ( has_filter( 'impress_showcase_property_url_suffix' ) ) {
            $url = $url . apply_filters( 'impress_showcase_property_url_suffix', $suffix = http_build_query( array() ), $prop, $this->idx_api );
        }

        if ( 1 == $show_image ) {
            $output .= apply_filters(
                'impress_showcase_property_html',
                sprintf(
                    '<div class="impress-showcase-property %17$s">
                    <a href="%3$s" class="impress-showcase-photo" target="%18$s">
                        <img src="%4$s" alt="%5$s" title="%6$s %7$s %8$s %9$s %10$s, %11$s" />
                        <span class="impress-price">%1$s</span>
                        <span class="impress-status">%2$s</span>
                        <p class="impress-address">
                            <span class="impress-street">%6$s %7$s %8$s %9$s</span>
                            <span class="impress-cityname">%10$s</span>,
                            <span class="impress-state"> %11$s</span>
                        </p>
                    </a>
                    <p class="impress-beds-baths-sqft">
                    %12$s
                    %13$s
                    %14$s
                    %15$s
                    </p>
                    %16$s
                    </div>',
                    price_selector( $prop ),
                    $prop['propStatus'],
                    $url,
                    $prop_image_url,
                    htmlspecialchars( $prop['remarksConcat'] ),
                    $prop['streetNumber'],
                    $prop['streetDirection'],
                    $prop['streetName'],
                    $prop['unitNumber'],
                    $prop['cityName'],
                    $prop['state'],
                    $this->hide_empty_fields( 'beds', 'Beds', ( empty( $prop['bedrooms'] ) ? '' : $prop['bedrooms'] ) ),
                    $this->hide_empty_fields( 'baths', 'Baths', ( empty( $prop['totalBaths'] ) ? '' : $prop['totalBaths'] ) ),
                    $this->hide_empty_fields( 'sqft', 'SqFt', ( empty( $prop['sqFt'] ) ? '' : $prop['sqFt'] ) ),
                    $this->hide_empty_fields( 'acres', 'Acres', ( empty( $prop['acres'] ) ? '' : $prop['acres'] ) ),
                    $this->maybe_add_disclaimer_and_courtesy( $prop ),
                    $column_class,
                    $target
                ),
                $prop,
                ( isset( $instance ) ? $instance : [] ),
                $url,
                $prop_image_url,
                $this->maybe_add_disclaimer_and_courtesy( $prop ),
                $column_class,
                $target
            );
        } else {
            $output .= apply_filters(
                'impress_showcase_property_list_html',
                sprintf(
                    '<li class="impress-showcase-property-list %13$s">
                    <a href="%2$s" target="%14$s">
                        <p>
                            <span class="impress-price">%1$s</span>
                            <span class="impress-address">
                                <span class="impress-street">%3$s %4$s %5$s %6$s</span>
                                <span class="impress-cityname">%7$s</span>,
                                <span class="impress-state"> %8$s</span>
                            </span>
                            <span class="impress-beds-baths-sqft">
                                %9$s
                                %10$s
                                %11$s
                                %12$s
                            </span>
                        </p>
                    </a>
                </li>',
                    price_selector( $prop ),
                    $url,
                    $prop['streetNumber'],
                    $prop['streetDirection'],
                    $prop['streetName'],
                    $prop['unitNumber'],
                    $prop['cityName'],
                    $prop['state'],
                    $this->hide_empty_fields( 'beds', 'Beds', ( empty( $prop['bedrooms'] ) ? '' : $prop['bedrooms'] ) ),
                    $this->hide_empty_fields( 'baths', 'Baths', ( empty( $prop['totalBaths'] ) ? '' : $prop['totalBaths'] ) ),
                    $this->hide_empty_fields( 'sqft', 'SqFt', ( empty( $prop['sqFt'] ) ? '' : $prop['sqFt'] ) ),
                    $this->hide_empty_fields( 'acres', 'Acres', ( empty( $prop['acres'] ) ? '' : $prop['acres'] ) ),
                    $column_class,
                    $target
                ),
                $prop,
                ( isset( $instance ) ? $instance : [] ),
                $url,
                $column_class,
                $target
            );
        }

        if ( 1 == $use_rows && ( 1 !== $count || 1 === $total ) ) {

            // close a row if..
            // num_per_row is a factor of count OR
            // count is equal to the max number of listings to show OR
            // count is equal to the total number of listings available
            if ( $count % $num_per_row == 0 || $count == $total || $count == $max ) {
                $output .= '</div> <!-- .impress-row -->';
            }

            // open a new row if..
            // num per row is a factor of count AND
            // count is not equal to max AND
            // count is not equal to total
            if ( $count % $num_per_row == 0 && $count != $max && $count != $total ) {
                $output .= '<div class="impress-row shortcode impress-property-showcase">';
            }
        }
    }

    return $output;

}
```

I can not understand how to override $this in functions PHP. what is the proper way to do that?

**Added filter code to my functions.php**

```
add_filter('impress_showcase_property_html', 'impress_showcase_property_html_callback', 10, 8);

if(!function_exists('impress_showcase_property_html_callback')) {
    /**
     * Update Layout
     * @param $prop
     * @param $url
     * @param $prop_image_url
     * @param $column_class
     * @param $target
     *
     * @return string
     */
    function impress_showcase_property_html_callback($value, $prop, $instance, $url, $prop_image_url, $column_class, $target){

        $value = sprintf(
            '<div class="impress-showcase-property %17$s">
                        <a href="%3$s" class="impress-showcase-photo" target="%18$s">
                            <img src="%4$s" alt="%5$s" title="%6$s %7$s %8$s %9$s %10$s, %11$s" />
                            <span class="impress-price">%1$s</span>
                            <span class="impress-status">%2$s</span>
                        </a>
                        <p class="impress-address">
                            <span class="impress-street">%6$s %7$s %8$s %9$s</span>
                            <span class="impress-cityname">%10$s</span>,
                            <span class="impress-state"> %11$s</span>
                        </p>                        
                        <p class="impress-beds-baths-sqft">
                        %12$s
                        %13$s
                        %14$s
                        %15$s
                        </p>
                        %16$s
                        </div>',
            price_selector( $prop ),
            $prop['propStatus'],
            $url,
            $prop_image_url,
            htmlspecialchars( $prop['remarksConcat'] ),
            $prop['streetNumber'],
            $prop['streetDirection'],
            $prop['streetName'],
            $prop['unitNumber'],
            $prop['cityName'],
            $prop['state'],
            $this->hide_empty_fields( 'beds', 'Beds', ( empty( $prop['bedrooms'] ) ? '' : '<span class="numbers">'.$prop['bedrooms'].'</span>' ) ),
            $this->hide_empty_fields( 'baths', 'Baths', ( empty( $prop['totalBaths'] ) ? '' : '<span class="numbers">'.$prop['totalBaths'].'</span>' ) ),
            $this->hide_empty_fields( 'sqft', 'SqFt', ( empty( $prop['sqFt'] ) ? '' : '<span class="numbers">'.$prop['sqFt'].'</span>' ) ),
            $this->hide_empty_fields( 'acres', 'Acres', ( empty( $prop['acres'] ) ? '' : '<span class="numbers">'.$prop['acres'].'</span>' ) ),
            $this->maybe_add_disclaimer_and_courtesy( $prop ),
            $column_class,
            $target
        );
        return $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "override $this"? If you just want to modify the shortcode output, then just hook your function on the `impress_showcase_property_html` filter and modify the HTML to your liking.

Comment: @SallyCJ How can I do that? it's getting an error with $this->function_name();

Comment: Does my answer help? If not, how/when/where did you call `add_filter()`?

Comment: @SallyCJ Apology to forgot to add filter code, please check the add_filter function now. $this->hide_empty_fields() and $this->maybe_add_disclaimer_and_courtesy( $prop ) is not working because it is another class method which coming from the plugins code.

Comment: Well in that case, what is the full code in that `Register_Impress_Shortcodes` class? Does it have a global instance like `global $class; $class = new Register_Impress_Shortcodes();`? Are those two methods (`hide_empty_fields()` and `maybe_add_disclaimer_and_courtesy()`)  public, protected or maybe private?

Comment: Does the revised answer help? If not or you need a specific example, then you should provide what's asked in that revised answer, e.g. the complete class code.

Comment: @SallyCJ Issue is not with the "Register_Impress_Shortcodes" class the filter that I have added in my functions.php is not working when I use $this->function_name() in my functions.php file.

Comment: Yes, as explained in the first paragraph in my revised answer - `$this` can't be used from within your global `impress_showcase_property_html_callback` function. Nonetheless, I just wanted to know how did you solve the issue??  Or is it not solved yet?

Answer (score 1):

So you're trying to call the `hide_empty_fields()` and `maybe_add_disclaimer_and_courtesy()` methods in the `Register_Impress_Shortcodes` class, from within a global function, and it's not impossible to call class methods from within such global functions, but you cannot use `$this` in your function because `$this` is only available from within a class method which is called from within an object context. [More details in the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

As for the proper way to call those two class methods from within your function, I'm not sure <sub>(unless maybe, if you provide the full class code and the information on how/when/where it's being instantiated)</sub>, but see below for some options that you can try, *without* modifying the core plugin files:

- If those methods are public and there's an instance of the class in the global scope, e.g. `global $Register_Impress_Shortcodes; $Register_Impress_Shortcodes = new Register_Impress_Shortcodes();`, then just add `global $Register_Impress_Shortcodes;` to your function (at the top), then replace those `$this` with `$Register_Impress_Shortcodes`.
- If such global instance is not available, but those methods are public and there is a "static instance getter" like the [`DBConn::getConn()` here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45459323), then in your function, just replace the `$this` with `Register_Impress_Shortcodes::instance()` (or replace `instance` with the correct method name).

  If such method doesn't exist, but/or the plugin in question provides a global function like `register_impress_shortcodes_instance()`, which returns the class instance, then replace those `$this` with `register_impress_shortcodes_instance()`.
- If those methods are **not public** or there's no global class instance, and neither an instance getter method or function, and that the `Register_Impress_Shortcodes` class can be extended, and also that those methods are ***not private***, then you can do something like this:

  ```php
  <?php
  // Extend the class.
  class My_Register_Impress_Shortcodes extends Register_Impress_Shortcodes {
      public function __construct() {
          // Add your filter.
          add_filter( 'impress_showcase_property_html', array( $this, 'impress_showcase_property_html_callback' ), 10, 7 );
      }

      // Now this is your filter callback which is a method in this class. So
      // you can now use $this and access the methods hide_empty_fields() and
      // maybe_add_disclaimer_and_courtesy() defined in the parent class.
      public function impress_showcase_property_html_callback( $value, $prop, $instance, $url, $prop_image_url, $column_class, $target ) {
          $value = sprintf(
              '... your code here',
              price_selector( $prop ),
              $prop['propStatus'],
              $url,
              $prop_image_url,
              htmlspecialchars( $prop['remarksConcat'] ),
              $prop['streetNumber'],
              $prop['streetDirection'],
              $prop['streetName'],
              $prop['unitNumber'],
              $prop['cityName'],
              $prop['state'],
              parent::hide_empty_fields( 'beds', 'Beds', ( empty( $prop['bedrooms'] ) ? '' : '<span class="numbers">'.$prop['bedrooms'].'</span>' ) ),
              parent::hide_empty_fields( 'baths', 'Baths', ( empty( $prop['totalBaths'] ) ? '' : '<span class="numbers">'.$prop['totalBaths'].'</span>' ) ),
              parent::hide_empty_fields( 'sqft', 'SqFt', ( empty( $prop['sqFt'] ) ? '' : '<span class="numbers">'.$prop['sqFt'].'</span>' ) ),
              parent::hide_empty_fields( 'acres', 'Acres', ( empty( $prop['acres'] ) ? '' : '<span class="numbers">'.$prop['acres'].'</span>' ) ),
              parent::maybe_add_disclaimer_and_courtesy( $prop ),
              $column_class,
              $target
          );

          return $value;
      }
  }

  function init_my_register_impress_shortcodes() {
      new My_Register_Impress_Shortcodes();
  }
  add_action( 'init', 'init_my_register_impress_shortcodes' );
  ```

  **Note:** Be sure to remove the `add_filter('impress_showcase_property_html', 'impress_showcase_property_html_callback', 10, 8);` in your code.
- If the class **cannot be extended** or you're having trouble calling those methods from within your class, then I guess you would want to [unregister/remove the shortcode](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_shortcode/) added by that class/plugin, then copy that very class, rename it and re-add the shortcode you have removed.

  That way, you wouldn't need to hook on `impress_showcase_property_html` and simply modify the shortcode output in the `property_showcase_shortcode()` method...

  But the problem with this (and the previous option), is that when the plugin is updated, you would need to revise your class/methods so that it's in sync with the latest code in the updated plugin.

Another option that you can try, is *if possible*, create 2 global functions (e.g. `my_hide_empty_fields()` and `my_maybe_add_disclaimer_and_courtesy()`) which does what those methods do, respectively, i.e. basically copy the code in those methods... and edit it accordingly, e.g. remove any `$this` calls. Then just use your functions from within your `impress_showcase_property_html_callback()` function.